# Template tag content is empty

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to use a `template` tag inside an Angular component.

Following the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) I created a similar [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-tag).

In the original example, the `template` tag has no children but it's content has children. On my example it's the other way around. The template has the children and content is empty (open the console and click the button to see it).

As a result, trying to manipulate the cloned template content fails.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  click() {
    const template: HTMLTemplateElement = document.querySelector('#t');
    console.log(`template.childElementCount: ${template.childElementCount}`);
    console.log(`template.content.childElementCount: ${template.content.childElementCount}`);
    const content = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    console.log(content.querySelector('.c2'));
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="click()">test</button>
<template id="t">
    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">{{ name }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Console result**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an open bug about this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15557

As a workaround I created the `template` with [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

```js
const name = "answer";
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `<div class="c1"><div class="c2">${name}</div></div>`;
console.log(`template.childElementCount: ${template.childElementCount}`);
console.log(`template.content.childElementCount: ${template.content.childElementCount}`);
const content = document.importNode(template.content, true);
console.log(content.querySelector('.c2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `template` and not `template.content`as first argument.

```js
const content = document.importNode(template, true);
console.log(content.querySelector('.c2'));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the difference?

Comment: In the documentation example, a whole node is set as the first argument. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode#Example
But I agree with you it should accept an argument of type DocumentFragment.

Comment: The example you mention doesn't help as it doesn't involve a template tag. It just clones some node...