# Template content is an empty document fragment

Tags: javascript, html, thingsboard

**Not a duplicate of [Template tag content is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676050/template-tag-content-is-empty) - A bug in Angular, while my question is about Vanilla Js.**

---

I am working on a [ThingsBoard](https://thingsboard.io/) widget. In [the HTML tab](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/#resourceshtmlcss-section), I have this simple template:

```
<template id="myTemplate">
  <div>Test</div>
</template>
```

In the JS tab, I am trying to get the contents of this template (to eventually clone it):

```
const template = document.querySelector("#myTemplate");
console.log(template.content);
```

However, I am getting an *empty* [`DocumentFrgament`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment):
[image: Empty document-fragment]

This is very strange since when I run it outside of ThingsBoard (for example here on a StackOverflow snippet), I *do* get the contents of the template:

```js
const template = document.querySelector("#myTemplate");
console.log(template.content);
```

```html
<template id="myTemplate">
  <div>Test</div>
</template>
```

[image: Non-empty ducment-fragment]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your ThingsBoard example is using React or a similar DOM library, it might be programmatically creating the DOM, which could cause this issue.

When a `<template>` is constructed programmatically, using `appendChild`, the `content` remains empty.
For example:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
console.log(template.content); // #document-fragment (empty)
```

Instead of `template.appendChild`, you must use `template.content.appendChild` for it to work correctly.

I hope this helps in some way!

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain this behavior to me? Why would `content` remain empty when the `template` is constructed programmatically?

Comment: Apparently, when the HTML parser sees the `<template>` tag, it transfers all children into the `content` document fragment.  The template's actual `children` will be empty.  Same happens if you set `template.innerHTML`.

But if you append children to the template programmatically, they do not automatically transfer to the `content` fragment, which is surprising.  
It seems like this should be fixed, but there might be some valid reason why they don't want to change it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was super helpful in debugging a issue.